# FileLoadException Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Acabo de actualizar (vía NUGET) la versión de FluentMigrator de 1.6.2 a 3.1.3 y si bien en mi entorno local no tengo problemas (más allá de las adaptaciones necesarias por cambio de versión) cuando integro los cambios al servidor estoy recibiendo el mensaje:

> Class Initialization method Infraestructura.Test.Repositories.Persistence.RestoreDB.FixtureSetup threw exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: System.IO.FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040).

He intentado la solución propuesta [aquí](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8474) pero no funcionó.

Qué otra cosa puedo intentar?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La migración de FluentMigrator de 1.6.2 a 3.1.3 trae también un cambio importante y es que han separado la ejecución por línea de comando, con lo cuál hay que instalar [FluentMigrator Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentMigrator.Console/) y luego llevar las DDLs necesarias dónde se esté ejecutando el Migrate.exe.